# Issue in setting the background color in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, scatter-plot, pyqtgraph, setbackground

I've  got an issue when using the pyqtgraph module in python.
When I put a white background color to a glscatterplot, the scatter dots just vanish. It is like if the color of background was added to the color of the scatterplot therefore everything is white. 
Here is a piece of the code I use:

```
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.setBackgroundColor('w')
w.show()
sp3 = gl.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=np.transpose(pos3), color=rgba_img, size=1, pxMode=False)
w.addItem(sp3)
```

If I replace ('w') by ('k') in the setBackgroundColor method the color of scatter is fine and the background is black. Did anyone else ever get this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason is that you haven't set the foreground colour.
try:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
```

Comment: I have the same problem as @ymmx and this solution didn't work for me. I am running python2.7 on my Debian 8. It actually seems to me as a bug.

Comment: @drali I don't have OpenGl installed so can't test, try modifying the colour (eg for the initial example sp3.setData(color = [0,1.0,0, 1.0]))

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I found the solution here: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/193. I think is the same question so probably you already know the solution but I report it here simplified because.

The problem is that there is an option for GLScatterPlotItem called glOptions. By default, 'additive' is used (see [pyqtgraph.opengl.GLGraphicsItem.GLOptions](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLGraphicsItem.html)). You can change it to 'translucent' like so:

```
sp3.setGLOptions('translucent')
```

In this way you won't have any problem changing the background color to white, nor the scatter color to black (I had both problems).

Comment: This also fixes dense scatterplots from becoming one big white blob. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

In pyqtgraph, you construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

def mkQApp():
    global QAPP
    QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
    # work around a variety of bugs in the native graphics system
    inst = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if inst is None:
        QAPP = QtGui.QApplication([])
    else:
        QAPP = inst
    return QAPP


app = pg.mkQApp()
view  = pg.GraphicsView()#useOpenGL = True)
color='w'
view.setBackground(color)
view.show()
```

then you could use: `plot = pg.PlotItem()` etc.